# Breaking Wudu during tawaf

Tags: wudu

If a person did 3 rounds and he redo the wudu then he should started it again its tawaf with zero?or he can start with 4th round considering the previous ones too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As salamu aleykum warahmatullahi wa barakatuh

According to my dad, Tawaf is like prayer so if a person did 3 rounds he has to redo the wudu and start all over again. NO he cannot consider the previous ones even though he was on the sixth round, he has to start all over again.
 Thanks

Comment: How is your dad an authority in Islamic jurisprudence? Clarify!